# Update a "most current record flag" on the last inserted record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, version-control

I have a table that is versioned by having an auto increment column (to track the order that records are entered) and a "CURRENT_FLAG" that is set to 1 for the last inserted record. Views that join this table always use CURRENT_FLAG=1 so that they return only the last record.

So if the structure is like this:

```
AUTO_ID   PERSON_ID   PERSON_VALUE   CURRENT_FLAG
1         1           5452           0
2         1           637            1
3         2           4523           1
```

The next time I want to insert a record I need to update the CURRENT_FLAG. Right now I execute something like this:

```
UPDATE T
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT PERSON_ID, MAX(AUTO_ID) as AUTO_ID 
      FROM T 
  GROUP BY PERSON_ID
         ) as T1 ON T.PERSON_ID = T1.PERSON_ID and T.AUTO_ID = T1.AUTO_ID
SET T.CURRENT_FLAG = COALESCE(T.PERSON_ID / T.PERSON_ID, 0)
```

That query, though, takes several seconds on a rather small table even with indexes on both PERSON_ID and AUTO_ID.

The records are inserted as a batch from a staging table, and are not inserted one person at a time, so I can't pull up the auto_ids and set the flag manually or set all the current_flags to 0.

Does anyone have a better way to write that query, or to do the same thing with triggers and\or some other solution? MySQL 5.0+.

Comment: given it's an auto increment column, why not simply `select ... where auto_id=max(auto_id)`, instead of having to fuss around with this extra field+updates?

Comment: Is your index a multicolum index with both PERSON_ID and AUTO_ID (in that order)?

Comment: I have two separate indexes, one on each field. Would adding an index on PERSON_ID and AUTO_ID (in that order) speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to get the most recently added record instead of having an extra `CURRENT_FLAG` column. You can try order descending and getting the first record:

```
SELECT [field1, field2, etc...] FROM `T`
WHERE [...]
ORDER BY AUTO_ID DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Marc B. Instead of keeping this CURRENT_FLAG in the table, and beating up your server to keep it current, simply grab the latest record for each person, like so:

```
  SELECT T.*
     FROM T
     WHERE AUTO_ID IN 
     (
          SELECT MAX(AUTO_ID) AS AUTO_ID
            FROM T
        GROUP BY PERSON_ID
      )
```

You can define this as a view.  If you apply a WHERE clause to it, like

```
   WHERE T.PERSON_ID = :somebody
```

the optimizer will do the right thing as long as you have indexes on PERSON_ID and AUTO_ID.

Comment: Wouldn't it just make the view's slower, since its having to do this each time the view is queried. Also, if there are multiple tables joined its a lot of extra joining...

Comment: Gave me a thought, though. What if the update statement was something like `UPDATE T SET CURRENT_FLAG=1 WHERE AUTO_ID IN (SELECT MAX(AUTO_ID) AS AUTO_ID FROM T GROUP BY PERSON_ID)`. Would that be faster, you think?

Comment: OK. But you have to clear the previously set CURRENT_FLAG items too, the way I understand your use of CURRENT_FLAG.